# Eliminating $\theta$ from the system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

That's a modified exercise taken from a admission test to a university.

Let $x$, $y$ and $\theta$ real numbers such that
$$\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x\sin \theta + y \cos \theta = 2a \sin \theta\\
x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta = a \cos \theta\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $a$ is a real constant.
How can we determine two real constants $\mu$ ($\mu>0$) and $k$ such that
$$(x+y)^\mu+(x-y)^\mu=k$$
without using brute force?

Comment: Hi! Almost 9 years have passed! Hope I am not disturbing you. I guess you have already solved this. If not, are you interested in a solution? I can help :)

Comment: Hi! Yes, I'm interested in your approach, @Flagged.

Comment: Sure, though a minor correction. I think it should be $\cos 2\theta$ in the R.H.S. of second equation in order to get the desired answer. (This is a standard exercise in trigonometry)

Comment: Also in the meantime, I have found this question on [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365325/1003172). If you are satisfied with the answers there, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, @Flagged, there is really a typo, but in the first equation. The R.H.S. should be $2a\sin \theta$. Corrected.

Comment: Without further requirements on $k,\mu$, they can be anything you want. We'd have some real numbers, exponentiated, equal to another real number. What is the goal of the question?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342525/947379). (Same method is applied here)