# Eliminate $\theta$ from the equation

Tags: trigonometry

$x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta = \cos 2\theta$

$x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta = 2 \sin 2\theta$

I tried to use cross multiplication method to find $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ and then put the values in $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$, but was not able to eliminate $\cos 2\theta$ or $\sin 2\theta$. Please help me in solving this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why you rejected my edit?

Comment: Is this a system of equations?

Comment: You need to *eliminate* (??) $\;\theta\;$...or to solve for $\;x\,,\,\,\,y\;$ ?

Comment: Eliminate theta

Comment: We have n+1 equations to eliminate n unknowns, here we have two equations to eliminate one unknown that being theta

Comment: You could say if you want to solve for $(x,y)$. To me, it was not clear at all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214326/eliminating-theta-from-the-system-x-sin-theta-y-cos-theta-sin4-theta-x/3214708?r=SearchResults#3214708

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209847/eliminate-theta-from-lambda-cos2-theta-cos-theta-alpha-space-and/3213526?r=SearchResults#3213526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once solved in $\theta$ you'll get $\begin{cases}
x &= &3\cos(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)^3 \\
y &= &3\sin(\theta)-2\sin(\theta)^3 \end{cases}$

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xdlons0rzq

You can graph it (green curve) and notice this is an astroid.

Although it is rotated and stretched compared to the reference astroid (the one inscribed in the unit circle:  [wikipedia:astroïde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astro%C3%AFde))

So we will first apply the transformation $\begin{cases} u=\frac{x+y}{2\sqrt{2}}\\v=\frac{x-y}{2\sqrt{2}}\end{cases}$

To obtain the red curve which is now the standard one.

According to the wiki page it has equation $$(u^2+v^2-1)^3+27u^2v^2=0$$

Bu substituting $x,y$ we can get a cartesian equation but it is not very nice:

$x^6+3x^4y^2+3x^2y^4+y^6+15x^4-78x^2y^2+15y^4+48x^2+48y^2-64=0$

Comment: The *nice equation* is $(x+y)^{2/3}+(x-y)^{2/3}=2$. :)

Answer (score 2):

Multplying the first equation by $\sin \theta$ gives

$$x \cos\theta\sin \theta -y\sin^2\theta = \sin\theta \cos 2\theta\tag{1}$$

and the second by $\cos \theta$ will give

$$ x \cos\theta\sin \theta + y \cos^2\theta = 2\sin 2\theta \cos \theta\tag{2}$$

so we can eliminate the $x$ by subtracting 1 from 2:

$$y (\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = 2\sin 2\theta \cos \theta - \sin\theta \cos 2\theta$$

so $$y =  2\sin 2\theta \cos \theta - \sin\theta \cos 2\theta$$

Now we can maybe simplify by using the [double angle formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html):

$$\sin 2\theta = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta$$ and

$$\cos 2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$$

Try it. And then solve $x$ by a similar multiplication and substraction or adding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I believe we do not have to solve for x and y rather eliminate theta to give an equation

Comment: @Samuel. This is what I suspected (see my comment) and then my answer.

Comment: @Samuel I wanted to show how you can express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: @Flagged I only sketched the answer for the OP to fill in. I could find $x$ if I wanted to. We usually don't give full answers on this site...

Answer (score 0):

$$x \cos (\theta)-y \sin (\theta)=\cos (2 \theta )\tag 1$$
$$x \sin (\theta)+y \cos (\theta)=2\sin (2 \theta )\tag 2$$

$$(1)^2+(2)^2\implies x^2+y^2=4 \sin ^2(2 \theta)+\cos ^2(2 \theta)=\frac{1}{2} (5-3 \cos (4 \theta))\implies \theta=??? $$

Comment: So $x^2 + y^2 = 3\sin^2 2\theta + 1$. What does that buy us?

Comment: Except an alternative proof of boundedness of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Continued on with @Henno_Brandsma y expression, and let $s=\sin\theta, c=\cos\theta$:

$y =  2\sin 2\theta \cos \theta - \sin\theta \cos 2\theta = 4s(1-s^2)-s(1-2s^2) = 3s-2s^3$

Substitute back to equation 1:

$cx = \cos(2\theta) + s(3s-2s^3) = (2c^2-1)+(1-c^2)(1+2c^2)=3c^2-2c^4$
$$x = 3c-2c^3$$
We want even powers for s and c, so that we can use identity, $s^2 + c^2 = 1$

$x^2 = (3c-2c^3)^2 = \large 2 - {3(2c^2-1)^2 \over 2} + {(2c^2-1)^3\over2}=2-{3\cos^2(2\theta)\over 2}+{\cos^3(2\theta) \over2}$

$y^2 = (3s-2s^3)^2 = \large 2 - {3(2s^2-1)^2 \over 2} + {(2s^2-1)^3\over2}=2-{3\cos^2(2\theta)\over 2}-{\cos^3(2\theta) \over2}$

$$x^2-y^2 = \cos^3(2\theta)$$
$$x^2+y^2 = 4-3\cos^2(2\theta)$$

$$\cos^6(2\theta)=(x^2-y^2)^2=\left({4-x^2-y^2 \over 3}\right)^3$$
$$y^6+(3x^2+15)y^4 + (3x^4-78x^2+48)y^2+(x^6+15x^4+48x^2-64)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Square and add to find $$x^2+y^2=\cos^22t+4\sin^22t$$

$$2(x^2+y^2)=1+\cos4t+4(1-\cos4t)$$

$$\implies\cos4t=?$$

To eliminate $2t,$

$$(2\cos2t)^2+(2\sin2t)^2=x^2(\sin^2t+(2\cos t)^2)+y^2(4\sin^2t+\cos^2t)$$

$$\implies8=x^2(1-\cos2t+2(1+\cos2t))+y^2(2(1-\cos2t)+1+\cos2t)$$

$$\implies\cos2t=?$$

Now use $\cos2(2t)=2(\cos2t)^2-1$ to eliminate $2t$